# 'Key not valid for use in specified state' when exporting X509Certificate2 in .Net 5

Tags: export, .net-5, x509certificate2, pfx, pkcs#12

I have an app that does the following...

- I created a RSACng key and stored in memory
- I created a csr using the created rsa key and submitted it to public CA

```
var request = new CertificateRequest(
                distinguishedName,
                rsaKey,
                HashAlgorithmName.SHA384,
                RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
```

- I get the certificate file back and saved to disk
- Then I want to create a pkcs12 for this certificate and the associated private key as below but got the "key not valid.." error

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile).CopyWithPrivateKey(rsaKey);
cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "somepassphrase")
```

Tried specifying the private key to be exportable but that didn't help, not sure if that's the correct way since there isn't a X509Certificate2 constructor that accepts the rsa object

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile, "privateKeyPassphrase", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable).CopyWithPrivateKey(rsaKey);
cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "somepassphrase")
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is thrown because your private key is not exportable. You have to specify export policy when creating `RSACng` object (through the constructor that accepts `CngKey` instance).

Answer (score 0):

I now have the pcks12, in it this certificate and it's certificate chain.

```
var certsCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certsCollection.Add(cert);
certsCollection.Add(rootCert);
File.WriteAllBytes(pkcs12File, certsCollection.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "somepassphrase"));
```

If I then import it as below and look at what the export policy of that certificate, it's showing as None, why is that?

```
 var colCerts = new X509Certificate2Collection();
 colCerts.Import(pkcs12File, "somepassphrase");
```

Comment: Because import operation defaults to non-exportable keys. You need to use `X509Certificate2Collection.Import(string, string?, X509KeyStorageFlags)` overload and pass `Exportable` flag in third parameter.